# parsing Json where ID is an integer using gson

Tags: java, android, json, youtube, gson

I want to parse the following Json file in Java. But I am not able to parse it because the tag is an integer. Please suggest a method to parse the following data:

```
content:
{ 
    1: "rtsp://v6.cache3.c.youtube.com/CiILENGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp",
    5: "https://www.youtube.com/v/VWDc9oyBj5Q?version=3&f=videos&app=youtube_gdata",
    6: "rtsp://v8.cache7.c.youtube.com/CiILENZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp"
}
```

Comment: Which JSON parser are you using?

Comment: get id as string, after you convert that string to int

Comment: Suppose i have json file like this :
content :
{
   title: "Hello WOrld"
}

Then the variable name is title in the class content. So how does it work for the above thing??

Comment: @ArpitLearning: The trivial difference between "1" and "title" is that the latter is a valid variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens if you create fields like following in the object that you try to parse it too:

```
@SerializedName("1") 
public String number_1;
```

I assume you use gson.

Comment: @ArpitLearning super, wasn't sure it would work but was the only thing I thought might work.

Comment: In case there're many fields like this, I'd suggest to use a [FieldNamingPolicy](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/FieldNamingPolicy.html).